# CDI JPA - DAO pattern without EJB

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-6, cdi, java-ee-7

I am writing a CDI-JPA DAO pattern that not using EJB because I am using Tomcat.
Here is my code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "unitName1")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void saveUser(User user) {
        this.entityManager.persist(user);
    }

    public void removeUser(User user) {
        this.entityManager.remove(user);
    }

    public void getUser(int id) {
        this.entityManager.find(User.class, id);
    }
}
```

Since all my DAO classes are annotated with `@ApplicationScoped` so I was wondering whether IT IS SAFE to inject entityManager using `@PersistenceContext` as I did? Can someone tell me is that ok? If NOT, please give me your ideas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [@ApplicationScoped CDI bean and @PersistenceContext - is this safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885918/applicationscoped-cdi-bean-and-persistencecontext-is-this-safe)

Comment: Not directly related to your question. But you'll probably have issues by developing a CDI DAO under tomcat. Tomcat doesn't provide a transaction manager and CDI doesn't include one. It allows to use one without EJB thru the new @Transactional included in JTA 1.2 but tomcat doesn't have JTE implementation included. for that reason, I would recommend you to use TomEE instead of Tomcat, you'll have CDI, JPA and JTA included without having to bother their integration.

Comment: The Deltaspike Module for JPA provides @Transactional