# EntityManager inject good practice

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, cdi

As in the title - why using CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection) to inject an `EntityManager` (using Producer and `@Inject` annotation) is called a good practice? Why is it better than using `@PersistenceContext` annotation? I read that it is a preferred implementation but I cannot find why.

Comment: Just as a side-note: CDI stands for "contexts and dependency injection."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CDI](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html) is the standard technology for dependency injection in Java EE and it makes it *convenient* to create a method producer for the [`EntityManager`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) then you can simply inject into your beans.

The [`@PersistenceContext`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) annotation has a number of configurable elements (such as [`name`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html#name--)) and you may not want to duplicate them all over the application, for example.

CDI injection is specially useful when you have *multiple* persistence units. Then you can take advantage of CDI qualifiers for injection:

```
public class Databases {

    @Produces @Users 
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="UserData")
    EntityManager userEntityManager;

    @Produces @Documents
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="DocumentData")
    EntityManager docDatabaseEntityManager;
}
```

```
@Inject @Users
EntityManager em;
```

```
@Inject @Documents
EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation! I read also that injecting via PersistenceContext is not thread safe - is it correct?

Comment: @Adam `EntityManager` is not thread safe. But you should read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24643863/1426227) for further details.

Comment: @Adam The question is, why do you need "thread-safeness". Normally the container controls what is running in parallel threads and which instances are shared. In that case you do not need to be concerned about threadsafety of injected EntityManager-Instances. Each thread will work using its own transaction and therefore its own EntityManager.