# Is javax.persistence.EntityManager thread safe

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I’m using EntityManager in may Dao layer without @PersistenceContext but Dao method is calling service method which is marked as @Transactional. My question is should I use EntityManagerFactory in dao layer and every time get EntityManager to keep thread safety or it’s handled already?

Dao layer:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDaoImpl {

 private final EntityManager em;

 public void save(User user){
     em.persist(user);
 }
}
```

Service layer:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

 private final UserDao userDao;

 @Transactional
 public void save(User user) {
   userDao.save(user);
 }
}
```

Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

just add @PersistenceContext to your Entity Manager and the container will handle it for you, but if you are not in JEE environment so create your own entity manager factory, but I think in your current case the entity manager will still null. Also you must create you persistence unit XML file, and take attention in transaction-type, it must be JTA if you use @PersistenceContext and it should be RESSOURCE_LOCAL if you will create your own Entity Manager Factory.

Comment: I’m using Spring Boot 2+ and it’s working correctly, just wanted to make sure if it’s thread safe in my case or I need to add @PersistenceContext on it.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot so you don't need @PersistenceContext.

Comment: So Spring Boot will handle everything?

Comment: I think yes because you are already using @Transactional, so spring will handle transactions for you, take a look at this: https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional

Answer (score 0):

This stackoverflow question [Is EntityManager really thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643863/is-entitymanager-really-thread-safe) already got answer to your question.

And this one "[Future-Proofing Java Data Access - DAO Pattern Done Right](https://www.nvisia.com/insights/future-proofing-java-data-access-dao-pattern-done-right)" shows how to design DAO layer.

But if you are using Spring and Spring Data repository then I would suggest defining repository using CrusRepository or JpaRepository interface.
That would offload your concerns regarding EntityManager handling to Spring.