Using custom entityManager in multi-threaded environment
I used EntityManager to do some custom queries, but I encountered some issues.

Firstly, I defined entityManager as a singleton bean,

@Configuration
public class PrimaryJpaConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager(@Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }
}

and injected into my service,
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void doSomething() {
        ......
        jakarta.persistence.Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(someSql);
        nativeQuery.unwrap(NativeQueryImpl.class).setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
            List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = nativeQuery.getResultList();
        ......
    }

}


but if multiple users request my service at the same time, my backend will throw an exception "The statement has been closed".  and then I realized that entityManager is not thread-safe, I guess it's because multiple threads got the only entityManager at the same time, and the first thread created a statement using entityManager and after execution released the statement, the latter threads can not get statement.
2.So I intended to make entityManager prototype, so I added @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)  annotation above my entityManager bean.
then my code be like:
    @Primary
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager(@Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }
}

but this would result in another issue, database connection leak.. I can't figure out why this happened, as the beans are managed by container, they should be released after use.

after searching on Google, somebody said can use @PersistenceContext to inject bean, and I tried,
my code:

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager(@Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }
}

@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
    @PersistenceContext(name = "primaryEntityManager")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void doSomething() {
        ......
        jakarta.persistence.Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(someSql);
        nativeQuery.unwrap(NativeQueryImpl.class).setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
            List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = nativeQuery.getResultList();
        ......
    }

}


unfortunately, I encountered another issue, ClassCastException: class jdk.proxy2.$Proxy288 cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl

Finally, I don't know why, I added @Transactional above my service and seems issue solved.
like this:

@Transactional
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
    @PersistenceContext(name = "primaryEntityManager")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void doSomething() {
        ......
        jakarta.persistence.Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(someSql);
        nativeQuery.unwrap(NativeQueryImpl.class).setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
            List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = nativeQuery.getResultList();
        ......
    }

}


Oh.. My environment: SpringBoot 3.1.11, hibernate-core: 6.2.24.Final, HikariCp: 5.0.1
Can anyone explain this, thanks!

EntityManager is thread safe in a Stateless bean : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643863/is-entitymanager-really-thread-safe

Using @PersistenceContext instead of defining EntityManager as a @Bean directly is indeed recommended, as Spring's @PersistenceContext injection automatically manages EntityManager instances per request/transaction scope, ensuring thread safety and avoiding connection leaks.
@Configuration
public class EntityManagerConfig {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Bean
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return this.entityManager;
    }

Spring will manage the EntityManager lifecycle, and you avoid the risk of leaks or exceptions from multi-threaded access.

Thanks for your advice. But for my situation, I have multiple data sources, that's why I need to define them, for example, for serviceA, I need primaryEntityMnager, and for serviceB I may need secondaryEntityManager.
